# Change state on Drag and Drop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having a todo-list made with React. It is having 3 section:- "Todo", "In Progress" and  "Done". I've implemented drag-and-drop functionality to this list. It works pretty fine. But, after the drag-and-drop, the state is not updating. How can I update the state after the drop?

Functionality:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState({
todo: [
  {
    _id: 233243424,
    name: "This is a Todo",
  },
  {
    _id: 1123434,
    name: "This is a second Todo",
  },
],
inProgress: [
  {
    _id: 1123243,
    name: "This is a In Progress",
  },
  {
    _id: 55322234,
    name: "This is a second In Progress",
  },
],
done: [
  {
    _id: 2455422,
    name: "This is a Done",
  },
  {
    _id: 33235345,
    name: "This is a second Done",
  },
 ],
});
  let draggableTodo = null;

  const dragStart = (event) => {
    draggableTodo = event.target;
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.style.display = "none";
    }, 0);
  };
  const dragEnd = (event) => {
    draggableTodo = null;
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.style.display = "block";
    }, 0);
  };

  const dragOver = (event) => event.preventDefault();

  const dragEnter = (event) => {};

  const dragLeave = (event) => (event.target.style.border = "none");

  const dragDrop = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.target.appendChild(draggableTodo);
   //Do Something here
  };
```

Structure:

```
 return (
 <div className="tasks">
  <div className="tasks_container">
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <div className="tasks-cont_menu"></div>
    <div className="tasks-cont_body">
      <div
        id="todo_div"
        className="tasks-body_child"
        onDragOver={dragOver}
        onDragLeave={dragLeave}
        onDrop={dragDrop}
      >
        <div className="tasks-bd_title">
          <h3>To Do</h3>
          <div className="tasks-child_status">3</div>
        </div>
        {tasks.todo.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={todo._id}
              className="tasks-bd_content"
              draggable={true}
              onDragStart={dragStart}
              onDragEnd={dragEnd}
            >
              {todo.name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div
        id="inProgress_div"
        className="tasks-body_child "
        onDragOver={dragOver}
        onDragEnter={dragEnter}
        onDragLeave={dragLeave}
        onDrop={dragDrop}
      >
        <div className="tasks-bd_title">
          <h3>In Progress</h3>
          <div className="tasks-child_status">1</div>
        </div>
        {tasks.inProgress.map((inprogress) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={inprogress._id}
              className="tasks-bd_content"
              draggable={true}
              onDragStart={dragStart}
              onDragEnd={dragEnd}
            >
              {inprogress.name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div
        id="done_div"
        className="tasks-body_child"
        onDragOver={dragOver}
        onDragEnter={dragEnter}
        onDragLeave={dragLeave}
        onDrop={dragDrop}
      >
        <div className="tasks-bd_title">
          <h3>Done</h3>
          <div className="tasks-child_status">5</div>
        </div>
        {tasks.done.map((done) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={done._id}
              className="tasks-bd_content"
              draggable={true}
              onDragStart={dragStart}
              onDragEnd={dragEnd}
            >
              {done.name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
```

Like, when a todo is dragged and dropped to the done section, the `tasks` state must update to reflect the change.

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've do refactoring and some code changes to make it work. Edit this on CodeSandBox to know how it works.

[image: Edit elegant-mcclintock-c9h77]

---

**Functionality:**

```
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState({
    todo: [
      {
        _id: 233243424,
        name: "This is a Todo"
      },
      {
        _id: 1123434,
        name: "This is a second Todo"
      }
    ],
    inProgress: [
      {
        _id: 1123243,
        name: "This is a In Progress"
      },
      {
        _id: 55322234,
        name: "This is a second In Progress"
      }
    ],
    done: [
      {
        _id: 2455422,
        name: "This is a Done"
      },
      {
        _id: 33235345,
        name: "This is a second Done"
      }
    ],
    dragged: {}
  });
  const draggableTodo = useRef(null);
  const groupName = useRef(null);

  const dragStart = (event) => {
    console.log("drag start");
    const { target } = event;
    const id = target.id;
    const parentElementId = target.parentElement.id;
    setTimeout(() => {
      target.style.display = "none";
      draggableTodo.current = target;
    }, 0);
    setTasks((prevState) => {
      // prevent mutation
      const state = { ...prevState };

      const fn = (name) => {
        groupName.current = name;
        state.dragged = state[name].find((i) => i._id.toString() === id);
      };

      switch (parentElementId) {
        case "todo_div":
          fn("todo");
          return state;
        case "inProgress_div":
          fn("inProgress");
          return state;
        case "done_div":
          fn("done");
          return state;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    });
  };
  const dragEnd = (event) => {
    console.log("dragEnd");
    event.preventDefault();
    draggableTodo.current.style.display = "block";
  };

  const dragOver = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  // const dragEnter = (event) => {};

  const dragLeave = (event) => {
    // event.target.style.border = "none";
  };

  const dragDrop = (event) => {
    console.log("drop");

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    const { currentTarget } = event;
    const id = currentTarget.id;
    setTasks((prevState) => {
      // This is to not mutate state object
      const state = { ...prevState };
      const fn = (name) => {
        const { current } = groupName;
        const dragged = state.dragged;
        const previousParentId = draggableTodo.current.parentElement.id;
        if (previousParentId !== id) {
          state[current] = state[current].filter((i) => i._id !== dragged._id);
          state[name] = [...state[name], dragged];
        } else {
          draggableTodo.current.style.display = "block";
        }
      };

      switch (id) {
        case "todo_div":
          fn("todo");
          return state;
        case "inProgress_div":
          fn("inProgress");
          return state;
        case "done_div":
          fn("done");
          return state;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    });
  };
```

---

**Structure:**

```
return (
    <div className="tasks">
      <div className="tasks_container">
        <h1>Tasks</h1>
        <div className="tasks-cont_menu"></div>
        <div className="tasks-cont_body">
          <div
            id="todo_div"
            className="tasks-body_child"
            onDragOver={dragOver}
            onDropCapture={dragDrop}
            style={{ border: "5px solid red" }}
          >
            <div className="tasks-bd_title">
              <h3>To Do</h3>
              <div className="tasks-child_status">3</div>
            </div>
            {tasks.todo?.map((todo) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={todo._id}
                  className="tasks-bd_content"
                  draggable={true}
                  onDragStart={dragStart}
                  onDragEnd={dragEnd}
                  id={todo._id}
                >
                  {todo.name}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div
            id="inProgress_div"
            className="tasks-body_child "
            onDragOver={dragOver}
            onDropCapture={dragDrop}
            style={{ border: "5px solid orange" }}
          >
            <div className="tasks-bd_title">
              <h3>In Progress</h3>
              <div className="tasks-child_status">1</div>
            </div>
            {tasks.inProgress?.map((inprogress) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={inprogress._id}
                  className="tasks-bd_content"
                  draggable={true}
                  onDragStart={dragStart}
                  onDragEnd={dragEnd}
                  id={inprogress._id}
                >
                  {inprogress.name}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div
            id="done_div"
            className="tasks-body_child"
            onDragOver={dragOver}
            onDropCapture={dragDrop}
            style={{ border: "5px solid green" }}
          >
            <div className="tasks-bd_title">
              <h3>Done</h3>
              <div className="tasks-child_status">5</div>
            </div>
            {tasks.done?.map((done) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={done._id}
                  className="tasks-bd_content"
                  draggable={true}
                  onDragStart={dragStart}
                  onDragEnd={dragEnd}
                  id={done._id}
                >
                  {done.name}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Heyy! That worked! Thank you

Comment: A more simple approach would be to use Sortable.js https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable

Answer (score 0):

a rough idea would be using a change handler

```
const changeHandler = e => {
  setTasks({...tasks, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

and using an event handler on dragdrop

```
onChange={changeHandler}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put functionality in the dragEnd function that you want to run when div is dropped.
The dragEnd event parameter should have the relevant data you need to be able to update the state correctly.